# nested json deserialization - need another set of eyes

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization, restsharp

I have been trying to get this json to deserialize for two days now using RestSharp.  I have gone through the RestSharp github site, looked at countless examples, and spent much time here on Stack Overflow to try and find the answer to no avail.  My code had previously worked perfectly but the vendor changed their API version and I was forced to do an update to keep using the application for my legal practice.  My json is as follows(client info has been removed and replaced with generic info):

```
    {
    "data":[
    {
    "id":1035117666,
    "client":
        {
        "id":905422394,
        "name":"client1"
        },
    "display_number":"11-00012",
    "description":"General",
    "practice_area":
        {
        "id":4269978,
        "name":"Business"
        },
    "status":"Open",
    "open_date":"2011-12-14",
    "close_date":null,
    "billing_method":"hourly"
    },
    {
    "id":1035117768,
    "client":
        {
        "id":905422506,
        "name":"client2"
        },
    "display_number":"12-00037",
    "description":"HOA",
    "practice_area":
        {
        "id":4269978,
        "name":"Business"
        },
    "status":"Open",
    "open_date":"2012-08-07",
    "close_date":null,
    "billing_method":"hourly"
    }
],
"meta":
    {
    "paging":
        {
        "next":"https://app.goclio.com/api/v4/matters.json?fields=id%2C+client%7Bid%2C+name%7D%2C+display_number%2C+description%2C+practice_area%7Bid%2C+name%7D%2C+status%2C+open_date%2C+close_date%2C+billing_method&limit=2&page_token=BAh7BjoLb2Zmc2V0aQc%3D--b1ea3eba20c8acefbcdfc7868debd1e0ee630c64&status=Open"
        },
    "records":91
    }
}
```

I built the following schema within my c# code:

```
public class MatterList
{
    public List<Matter> matters { get; set; }
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
    public Paging paging { get; set; }
    public int records { get; set; }
}

public class Paging
{
    public string previous { get; set; }
    public string next { get; set; }
}

[DeserializeAs(Name = "data")]
public class Matter
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Client client { get; set; }
    public string display_number { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public PracticeArea practice_area { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public DateTime open_date { get; set; }
    public DateTime close_date { get; set; }
    public string billing_method { get; set; }
    public string type = "matter";

}

public class PracticeArea
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the RestSharp deserialize method I am sending the result to an object of type MatterList using the following line of code

`MatterList matterList = jsonHandler.Deserialize<MatterList>(response);`

I have so far attempted to deserialize without the Meta or Paging POCO classes with the accompanying change to the MatterList class (taking out the Meta property).

I have tried with and without the [DeserializeAs(Name="data")] directive.

I have tried to set the RootElement of the json response prior to deserialization.

I have tried to shorthand the deserialization by combining it with the Execute request code
`IRestResponse<MatterList> matterList = client.Execute<MatterList>(request);`

I have created a container class called MatterContainer which I placed between MatterList and Matter classes in the schema:

```
public class MatterList
{
    public List<MatterContainer> matters { get; set; }
}

public class MatterContainer
{
    public Matter matter { get; set; }
}

public class Matter
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Client client { get; set; }
    public string display_number { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public PracticeArea practice_area { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public DateTime open_date { get; set; }
    public DateTime close_date { get; set; }
    public string billing_method { get; set; }
    public string type = "matter";

}
```

I know I am getting the json response back from the server correctly so my request is proper and MatterList is not null after deserialization.  The problem is that I cannot get the deserialization to actually populate the List matters within the MatterList class.

I have been looking at this off and on for two days and cannot get past this hurdle.  If anyone sees what I did wrong I would greatly appreciate the insight, I am at a point where I cannot progress  further with my application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* your `[DeserializeAs(Name = "data")]` attribute is in the wrong place. Try putting it in the root class instead:

```
public class MatterList
{
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "data")]
    public List<Matter> matters { get; set; }
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
}
```

alternatively, try renameing that property to `data`

Comment: Thank you so much!  I knew it was something simple.  You are absolutely correct, I put the DeserializeAs directive in the wrong place.  Moving it to within the Root class took care of the problem.